# How to perform a regular expression for a series of words separated by asterisks?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to make an expression that separates a series of words that start with a capital letter or & and that this group of words are separated by asterisks, I already made the regular expression to validate the group of words but I cannot separate this group of words by asterisks how to perform the regular expression for this series of words separated by asterisks?

```
^[A-Z&][(a-z)_-]+$
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bii4.png)

Comment: When `regex` comes to problem, this tool can help you build them [Regexr](https://regexr.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, try the following:

```
all([re.match(r"^[A-Z&][a-z_-]+$", word) for word in input_string.split("*")])
```

Explanation:
`input_str.split("*")` splits the input into parts delimited by asterisks. Then for each of them, `re.match(...)` checks whether the word conforms to your criterion. If it matches, it returns a "match" object which is "truthy", and `None` otherwise which is "falsy". Now `all(...)` returns true if and only if all the `re.match()` results are truthy.

Comment: It is not necessary to split the string in order to validate it.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do a regular string split here:

```py
inp = "&ello*Comonn*Lcd_da-*&lo"
parts = inp.split('*')
print(parts)  # ['&ello', 'Comonn', 'Lcd_da-', '&lo']
```

**Edit:**

If instead you want to assert that the input matches an asterisk-separated string using the pattern you provided above, then use `re.search`:

```py
inp = "&ello*Comonn*Lcd_da-*&lo"
if re.search(r'^[A-Z&][(a-z)_-]+(?:\*[A-Z&][(a-z)_-]+)*$', inp):
    print('MATCH')
else:
    print('NO MATCH')
```

Comment: Thanks friend, but what I have to do is validate that string with a regular expression that parses a string of that style, of words separated by * and with the condition of each group of words that starts with a capital letter or &, in the regular expression that I have no need to separate the words by *, regardless of the number of these, only that they meet the condition.

Comment: @BrayanStevendiaz I think I get it.  Check my updated answer for one option here.